# Add trailing zeros to a floating point number

Tags: sqlite

How can I add trailing zeroes to my result without using printf or format function in SQlite? I am using an older version that does not accept these functions. e.g

```
SELECT 3.00
```

gives me 3, but I want the value of 3.00

Comment: `SELECT '3.00'` is the trivial answer, beyond that is hard to answer without more context. What range of input/output are you expecting, and what are you going to be doing with the result? If you're using it in a different program it'll probably be easier to just do the formatting there instead.